# Remove a division by some attribute (not ID) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension and trying to remove some divisions using some attribute, like this:

HTML:

```
<div someAttr="value1=aaa&value2=bbb">Stack Overflow</div>
```

I know that it can be removed like this, if I know the value of `value1` and `value2`:

```
document.querySelector('[someAttr="value1=aaa&value2=bbb"]').remove();
```

---

But for a `<div>` as shown above, if I only know one of the values in `someAttr`, and I want to have an algorithm like:
(pseudo code)

```
var key = 12345;
if (value1 == key || value2 == key) {
    removeThisDiv();
}
```

What should I do (except examine HTML code as string manually)?

Answer (score 1):

Why use `||`, you can simply check the attribute value with `includes()`:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div');
var key = 12345;
if (el.getAttribute('someAttr').includes(key)) {
  el.remove();
}
```

```html
<div someAttr="value1=aaa&value2=12345">Stack Overflow</div>
```

**OR:** You can use [**Attribute selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) (contains:- `[attr*=value]`):

```js
var key = 12345;
var el = document.querySelector(`[someAttr*='${key}']`)
if(el) el.remove();
```

```html
<div someAttr="value1=aaa&value2=12345">Stack Overflow</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const someAttrDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div[someAttr]');

const key = "12345";

someAttrDivs.forEach(div => {
  const attrArr = div.getAttribute('someAttr').split('=');
  const value1 = attrArr[1].split('&')[0];
  const value2 = attrArr[2];

  if (value1 === key || value2 === key) {
    div.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div someAttr="value1=aaa&value2=bbb">Stack Overflow</div>
<div someAttr="value1=12345&value2=bbb">12345</div>
```

or you can use regular expression to get value of `value1` and `value2`.

```js
const someAttrDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div[someAttr]');

const key = "12345";

someAttrDivs.forEach(div => {
  const attrArr = div.getAttribute('someAttr');
  const value1 = attrArr.match(/value1=([a-z0-9]+)/)[1];
  const value2 = attrArr.match(/value2=([a-z0-9]+)/)[1];

  if (value1 === key || value2 === key) {
    div.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div someAttr="value1=aaa&value2=bbb">Stack Overflow</div>
<div someAttr="value1=12345&value2=bbb">12345</div>
```

Comment: For your first code block, if such attribute in `<div>`s may have two values or one, can I just modify `forEach` to this?:  ```someAttrDivs.forEach(div => {
    const attrArr = div.getAttribute('someAttr');
    if (attrArr.includes(key)) {
      div.remove();
    }
  });```

Comment: @Taihouuuuuuuuuuu - If you want the key to be present anywhere in the string, then yes. `includes` will check presence anywhere within the string. However, if you want to check whether value1 or value2 values are exactly equal to key, then use `===` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly match elements whose attribute values contains your target key using this syntax.

```js
document.querySelector('[someAttr*="12345"]').remove();
```

if you need to pass in this key dynamically, you can do

```js
const key = '12345'
const targetElement = document.querySelector(`[someAttr*="${key}"]`);

// Makes sense to check if element exists before attempting to call the remove method.
targetElement && targetElement.remove();
```

Read more https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp